# Google Maps Key Restrictions by IP Address not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to restrict access to my Google Maps API account by using IP Address to set up Key Restriction.  Previously I have been able to set up Key Restriction using the HTTP Referrer, but I do not seem to be able to get the same config happening using IP Addresses.  I have generated a new key to use with the IP Addresses (leaving the current using HTTP Referrer in play as it works).

As an example I can access the MAPS API from localhost/* but am unable to access it from 127.0.0.1 (using the new API key with AP Address key restrictions setup).  My actual website is hosted on a shared sever and using the domain name (perfectpets.com.au) with the HTTP referrer restriction all is good, but if I use the new API key with IP address restriction I get the RefererNotAllowedMapError  error.

Any tips on how to get this going would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IP address restrictions only work for web services, not the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem)

> Once restricted, a key will only work on platforms that support that type of restriction.
>
> - IP addresses (individual servers) - for use with the [web service APIs.](https://developers.google.com/maps/apis-by-platform#web_service_apis)
> - HTTP referrers (web sites) - for use with the [Web APIs.](https://developers.google.com/maps/apis-by-platform#web_apis/)

Comment: This is unfortunate because to use this public key for localhost development means assigning "localhost" as an allowed referrer, opening it up for anyone to use it from ANY "localhost".

Comment: Use a different key for development (with different restrictions)