# Request Denied by Google API: API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map API REST call through Outsystems platform:

[image]

However, if I specify a referrer in my Google Console, I get access denied, but it's working file without the referrer:

[image]

Why does setting a referrer in my Google Console cause an access denied error when using the API?

Answer (score 1):

related question [Google Maps Key Restrictions by IP Address not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134596/google-maps-key-restrictions-by-ip-address-not-working)

referrer restrictions only work for web APIs, not web services.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem)

> Once restricted, a key will only work on platforms that support that type of restriction.
>
> - IP addresses (individual servers) - for use with the [web service APIs.](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/)
> - HTTP referrers (web sites) - for use with the [Web APIs.](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/)